# Parent data not defined in vue.js component

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js

I have an `Orders` component that has a child `OrdersTable` component. My `Orders` component passes an array of object called `orders` to my `OrdersTable` component. However, when I try to use `orders` in the child component, it returns undefined.

Here is my `Orders` component snippet:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My Orders</h1>
        <orders-table :orders="orders" :token="token"></orders-table>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import OrdersTable from './OrdersTable.vue'

module.exports = {

    components: {

        OrdersTable

    },

    data: function () {
        return {
            orders: '',
            token: localStorage.getItem('jwt')
        }
    },

    created: function () {

        this.getAllOrders()

    },

    methods: {

        getAllOrders: function () {

            var token = localStorage.getItem('jwt')
            var self = this

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/orders',
                data: {token: localStorage.getItem('jwt')},
                success: function (data) {
                    self.orders = data
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    console.log(a)
                    console.log(b)
                    console.log(c)
                }
            })


        },

    },

}

</script>
```

Here is my `OrdersTable` component snippet:

```
<template>
    <div class="container"> 
        <v-client-table :data="orders" :columns="columns" :options="options"></v-client-table>
    </div>
</template>


<script>


module.exports = {

  data: function () {
    return {
        columns:['order_id', 'po_num','order_date', 'order_total'],
        tableData: orders, //returns undefined
        options: {
          dateColumns: ['order_date'],
          headings: {},
        },

    }

  },

  created: function () {
    console.log('orders:')
    console.log(this.orders) //returns undefined
  }

  props: ['orders']

}

</script>
```

I'm sure I passed data from the parent to child component correctly so I'm not really sure what's going on... Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems with your code:

1. You are trying to access undefined variable `orders` in your `data` function. You could try `this.orders` but this would also fail, see 2
2. You are trying to access `this.orders` in `created` hook, but your data is fetched using async call, so there's no guarantee that it will be there in `created`

Comment: yes - i thought it might have something to do with async... is there a way I can make sure the data loads before i can use this.orders?

Comment: You can use [watch](http://vuejs.org/api/#watch) to watch for property changes. This way your handler will always be called when the prop changes. You can also simply use `orders` in your template, for example in `v-for`, and Vue will make sure to update dom whenever `orders` change